# Расположение двух div друг над другом

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 div:

```css
.d1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
.d2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Первый div (.d1) перекрывает второй. Должно быть наоборот. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

У .d2 стоит `color`, вместо `background-color`, поэтому его не видно, и кажется, что .d1 его перекрыл.

По представленному коду видно только это.

Answer (score 2):

У каждого дива выставлено свойство `position:fixed;` то есть блоки буду позиционироваться относительно окна браузера + свойства `left:0; top:0;` смещают блоки на одну точку. Для того чтобы выставить их друг под другом необходимо для одного из блоков сделать сверху отступ равный высоте другого:

```
.d2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: yellow;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Как заметил mJeevas подправить свойство background-color

Answer (score 0):

Нет, всё верно, второй перекрывает первый. Просто ты перепутал `color` и `background-color`, поэтому второй прозрачный.

```css
.d1 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 1;
}
.d2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow; /*color: yellow;*/
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Убрать у обоих блоков `position: fixed`. Обернуть их в див и ему задать `position: fixed`

Comment: Добро пожаловать на ru.so. Пожалуйста выделяйте код в теги кода(фигурные скобки на панели инструментов редактора).